# Excel-like table filtering interface in R or Python?

Tags: python, r, excel, pivot-table

I'm wondering if some of the automatic filtering and subsetting tools that are built into Microsoft Excel have equivalents in any package in Python or R.

For instance, let's say I want to build a tool to filter job candidates by various characteristics (for a non-technical user of the tool). In Excel, I can hit the filtering button and then automatically start subsetting a spreadsheet using multiple-choice lists, numeric ranges, free text search, etc:

[image: filtering example]

I know Shiny apps in R allow you to build [interactive dashboards](https://uasnap.files.wordpress.com/2013/06/akcan_climate_app_screenshots01.png), but (a) they don't automatically discern the type of every column of your data set, and (b) I've found the Shiny reactive triggers to be a little glitchy when repeatedly subsetting the same data.

Again, this tool is intended to be used by a non-technical user, who is trying to narrow a large data set down to a set of matching entries using filtering.

EDIT: I've just been told about the DataTables library -- specifically [DT: An R interface to the DataTables library](http://rstudio.github.io/DT/), but it also can be used in Python. I'm still curious if there are better packages out there, but this one seems like the most likely candidate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rstudio has this ability. If you view a data set (click it in the Environment window), there's an option to "Filter".

Comment: Hadn't seen the new version that included that! Would love to have automatic multiple-choice lists as well, but that's a small complaint.

Comment: or type `View` for those without clicks

Comment: Not sure how this is an answer (much less how it was accepted). The OP wanted to build a tool, not use an IDE.